# What is best way to create elements and append them to the dom in jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

Let's say I am adding li elements in javascript code with jQuery.

**Example 1:**

```
for(var i=0 i<=5; i++){

    var li = $("<li/>");
    li.html("teest "+i);
    $("#ulid").append(li);

}
```

I've learned that the above example is a bad practice due to the fact that the loop rebuilds dom each time it hits append(li).

If that is the case, what is the best way to do the exact same thing as the above example?

Comment: *"I've learned that the above example is a bad practice due to the fact that the loop rebuilds dom each time it hits append(li)."* No it doesn't. It does a DOM `appendChild` operation, which is much smaller impact than "rebuilding". I'm not saying the above is the most efficient way to do it (it will probably cause a reflow on every pass), but it's not *that* bad. To be more efficient from a reflow perspective would require you start mucking about with a document fragment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing is probably fine for the vast majority of use cases. Your code will eventually call the DOM `appendChild` function once for each `li`, and I'm pretty sure that's also what all of the answers so far will do. And again, it's probably fine, though it may cause a reflow each time.

In those situations where you absolutely, positively need to avoid causing a DOM reflow on each pass through the loop, you probably need a [document fragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-B63ED1A3).

```
var i, li, frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
    li = $("<li>" + "teest "+i + "</li>");
    frag.appendChild(li[0]);
}
$("#ulid").append(frag); // Or $("#ulid")[0].appendChild(frag);
```

When you append a fragment, the fragment's *children* are appended, not the actual fragment. The advantage here being that being a single DOM call, you're giving the DOM engine the opportunity to add all the elements and only do a reflow at the end.

Comment: @Moon: :-) Very kind, and this is reasonably efficient (if you're going to use jQuery at all, you're trading a certain amount of efficiency for various benefits), but @dancek's answer also uses a document fragment, just behind-the-scenes. By doing it yourself you save the odd nanosecond, perhaps, but who knows what edge cases jQuery will handle for you if you go the jQuery route. Knowing what I know now, I might lean toward @dancek's approach. (Or not, I have to think about it more.)

Comment: @Moon: Just walked the code, and with @dtbarne's approach, jQuery *also* builds a document fragment for you behind the scenes. So you have all sorts of options. :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can include the inner HTML in the append text as well as multiple elements at a time, so just build one big string and append it just once.

```
var append_text = "";
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    append_text += "<li>test " + i + "</li>";
}
$("#ulid").append(append_text);
```

Comment: @dtbarne // that is a good example, but I'm looking for a solution with jQuery. What I mean by jquery is $("<li/>") so that I can use addClass, click(), and all other useful functions.

Comment: This is jQuery. It's just used more lightly.

Comment: @Moon: The above example is using jQuery, so you might want to come up with a better description of $("<li/>") than just "using jQuery". :)

Comment: @mellamokb, Adrian Schmidt // I would like to append an event inside a loop for each li element. So..I like use var li = $("<li/>"); then append an event by li.click(function(){});

Comment: @Moon: You can do that at the end after the loop: `$('li').click(function() { });`.  Or if you already have other `li` tags you don't want involved, give them all the same class.

Comment: Right, as @mellamokb said, you would just set the click event on the line following my sample.

Comment: In terms of causing DOM reflow (which is what I think the OP means by "rebuilding" the DOM), I don't know that this is any better. Have you walked through the jQuery code to see?

Comment: +1 I just walked the jQuery code, and it *doesn't* call `appendChild` each time, it builds a document fragment behind-the-scenes and then appends it once.

Answer (score 8):

The jQuery .append method accepts arrays of elements, so you can do this:

```
var elems = [];
for(var i=0; i<=5; i++){
    var li = $("<li/>");
    li.html("teest "+i);
    elems.push(li[0]); // Note we're pushing the element, rather than the jQuery object
}
$("#ulid").append(elems);
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks for clarifying. I hadn't even heard the "bad practice" claim before, so I was just guessing here. I thought if calling .append over and over again is a bad practice, surely jQuery devs have made calling it once with an array the good practice.

Comment: And a very reasonable assumption it was too. *And* you were right. I just walked the code, and they build a fragment in the background. Excellent. Slight bug in your code, though: `append` accepts an array of elements, but not an array of jQuery instances (which is slightly odd), just change `elems.push(li);` to `elems.push(li[0]);`. I've delete my erroneous comment.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: thanks for the fix. I didn't see that one coming :)

Comment: Yeah, it surprised me too. jQuery usually accepts a jQuery instance or a DOM element interchangeably, but apparently not here...